# How to create obiects with random data member values? C++

Tags: c++, random, stl

All my obiects generated by code below have the same values for randomNumber1 and randomNumber2. How to properly use std::default_random_engine?

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

class Food{

    public:
        int randomNumber1;
        int randomNumber2;
        Food(){
            std::default_random_engine generator;
            std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,40);
            std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution2(1,30);
            randomNumber1 = distribution(generator) * 20;
            randomNumber2 = distribution2(generator) * 20;
        };
};

int main(){

    Food * food = new Food();
    std::cout << food->randomNumber1 << " " << food->randomNumber2 << std::endl;
    Food * food1 = new Food();
    std::cout << food1->randomNumber1 << " " << food1->randomNumber2 << std::endl;
    Food * food2 = new Food();
    std::cout << food2->randomNumber1 << " " << food2->randomNumber2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you re-seed the `engine` (with the same seed) every time you create a `Food` object. What you could do is make it `static` so it's only seeded once:

```
static std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,40);
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution2(1,30);
randomNumber1 = distribution(generator) * 20;
randomNumber2 = distribution2(generator) * 20;
```

Or.. let the caller decide the seed.

Or, as @Unimportant says in the comments, use `std::random_device`:

```
static std::random_device dev;
static std::default_random_engine generator(dev());
```

Comment: Or better yet, provide it as a constructor argument.  `static`... that's up to the caller to decide :)

Comment: Or employ a `std::random_device` to get a truly random seed.

Comment: @Unimportant Yes, added.